# Plotting lognormal distribution

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, distribution, probability-density

This is the probability density function:

[image: Probability Density Function]

Code:

```
f=exp(-(((log(x)-log(100)-(.1((.15)^2)/2))^2))/(2*.15^2))/(x(.15)*sqrt(2*pi));

plot(f);
```

I can't seem to plot this lognormal distribution in Matlab. I am trying to find what percent of this graph is above 100, and don't know how to do that step in code.

Comment: @excaza I added the function in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'd want to give `x` some values and define f(x) as an ananymous function

```
f=@(x) exp(-(((log(x)-log(100)-(.1.*((.15).^2)./2)).^2))./(2*.15^2))./(x*.15*sqrt(2*pi));

x = 50:150
plot(x, f(x))
```

EDIT: Area of the density function for x>=100:

```
>> quad(f,100,Inf)
ans =  0.50299
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you! How would I be able to code how much of this graph is above 100?

Comment: area-wise you mean? `quad`, see my edit. It is 50,3%, dunno how much of it is due to numerical imprecision

Comment: percentage wise. If this is a normal distribution would this just be 50%?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has made this process even easier with the [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html), [`pdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.pdf.html), and [`cdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.cdf.html) functions**.

In the example below, the area above 25 is 0.0638 (6.38%).

```
pd = makedist('Lognormal',2,.8);     % Create Lognormal probability distribution object

X = (0:.01:50)';
figure, hold on, box on
p = plot(X,pdf(pd,X),'b-','DisplayName','A')      % Uses `pdf` function on the object
%legend('show')
title('Lognormal Distribution (\mu = 2, \sigma = 0.8)')
set(p,'LineWidth',2.0)

% Percent above 25
1-cdf(pd,25)        % = 0.0638    % Uses `cdf` function on the object
```

[image: PDF of Lognormal]

<sub>** Probability distribution objects introduced in MATLAB 2013a.</sub>